# Slider ValueChanged method command ( MVVM WPF Devexpress )

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm trying to bind a method to the value changed of a slider. 
I'm using devexpress poco,

XAML:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Height="140" Margin="20">
               <Slider Height="100" Width="40" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TickFrequency="10" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding VolumeLevel}">
                    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                         <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="ValueChanged" Command="{Binding Path=VolumeChangedCommand}" />
                    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
               </Slider>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My C# Code:

```
public void VolumeChanged()
{
     ...
}
```

The method never gets called.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your method defined ? In which `DataContext` ? Assuming your current XAML code, it has to be defined in the model/item class. (Which would be in `ListView.ItemsSource[i].VolumeChangedCommand`) - Also your `Command` has to implement the `ICommand` interface.

Comment: ValueChanged is the name of the event. Your VolumeChangedCommand should get invoked whenever this event is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are binding the slider to a `Command` (this line: `<dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="ValueChanged" Command="{Binding Path=VolumeChangedCommand}" />`), and you don't have a `Command` so it won't fire. All you need to do is add a `public Command VolumeChangedCommand`

```
private ICommand _VolumeChangedCommand;
public ICommand VolumeChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_VolumeChangedCommand == null)
            _VolumeChangedCommand = new CommandImplement();
        return _VolumeChangedCommand ;
    }
    set
    {
        _VolumeChangedCommand = value;
    }
}

class CommandImplement: ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    } 

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
         VolumeChanged(); //Call your method or put your code here.
    }
}
```